# The pagination doesn't work

Tags: pagination, loop

I have made a new WordPress Theme and I'm done .. but I have one problem. I can't get the pagination to work. I use the "wp-paginate" plugin and I have put the following code on my index.php:

```
<?php if(function_exists('wp_paginate')) {
wp_paginate();
} ?>
```

But that doesn't work for my site. There is still nothing on the frontend and in the markup. What can I do?

Here is my index.php:

```
    <?php get_header(); ?>


<div id="wraper">

<div id="main" role="main">

    <article>

    <?php if ( ! have_posts() ) : ?>
        <header>
            <h1>Nicht gefunden!</h1>
        </header>

        <p>Sorry, leider konnte der gew&uuml;nschte Artikel nicht gefunden werden. Vielleicht hilft Ihnen die suche ja weiter!</p>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php get_template_part( 'loop-index', 'index' ); ?>

    </article><!-- post -->

    <?php endwhile; ?>

</div> <!-- end #wraper -->

<?php if(function_exists('wp_paginate')) {
    wp_paginate();
} ?>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a new WordPress install, it is likely that you don't actually have enough posts to require pagination, and thus the pagination links aren't appearing.

Quick test: ensure you have at least **two** posts, then go to `Dashboard -> Settings -> Reading`, and change the "Posts Per Page" setting to `1`. Do you see pagination links?